# SISS Variables -

Tags: variables, ssis

I have created user defined SSIS variables at the package level.

Example: Here are the varibales

v1 = 10

v2 = 20

v3

The result should be V3 = V1 +V2 Where should i give this expression in the control flow and will i get the result

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Am I missing something or is there a reason an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141232.aspx) won't suffice?

Given variables defined as described above

[image: Variables window]

Set "Evaluate as Expression" to True on the variable v3 and for the Expression, use @[User::v1] + @[User::v2] (or click the ellipses and build the expression with the WYSIWYG editor)

[image: Properties window]

If you notice the pink corner of v3, that is due to me running an add-in called [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) which can assist in your SSIS development tasks but in no way affects the workings of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate variables within a Script Component.  If you're using SQL-Server 2005 you get to use VB.Net, if you're using 2008, you have the choice of that or C#.net.

Here are some (VB.net) examples of code I've used to get variables (strings in my case), manipulate them, and send them back to the variable storage area:

```
Dim logFilename As String
Dim logFilePath As String

' create filename
logFilePath = Dts.Variables("LogFilePath").Value.ToString()
curDate = Now().ToString("yyyyMMdd")
logFilename = "test-" & curDate & ".Log"
Dts.Variables("LogFileName").Value = logFilename
```

To do the same with your numbers, in the guts of the Script Component (I'm a bit rusty with VB)

```
Dim v1 as Int
Dim v2 as Int
Dim v3 as Int

// get your variables from the package 
v1 = Dts.Variables("v1").Value
v2 = Dts.Varuables("V2").Value
v3 = v1 + v2
// set your result back to the package
Dts.Variables ("v3").Value = v3
```